# Lost some keyboard keys while working on an application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, keyboard

Today, while working on a web application, I lost some of my keyboard keys. Even though I was pressing them again and again, it didn't have any affect. Once I closed Visual Studio and opened it again, the keys were working again. Its mostly the enter, delete and the backspace keys.

Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Comment: I think you already found the solution...

Comment: Its very frustrating to have to close the instance down and reopen it for it to work again with no gaurantee that it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens every once in a while, I believe you can hit `Alt + Enter` to get the keys to respond again instead of closing Visual Studio and opening it again.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a problem like this. I had to press the Alt + Enter key or the Ctrl + Tab keys to get it back.

Check out this Microsoft connect answer to a problem like this. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534869/arrow-keys-stop-working-in-editor

I also have an issue like this because I have ReSharper installed and it was taking up to much memory. And I don't know what I did, but I haven't had it happen to me in awhile. But if you have resharper or another plugin installed, check to see if it is using a lot of memory.